# Calender gadget shows a blank orange background in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, calendar, desktop-gadget

The date is not appearing in any gadgets I use.. the date is displayed in the system tray - but the Calender gadget shows an empty orange background. How can I fix this ?

Comment: `but when i use any calender gadgets` - there's only 1 calender gadget. Do you get any error messages? A screenshot of what happens when you had the gadget will be useful.

Comment: Scratch that, I encountered the same problem.

Comment: Comment by @Ralte: I use windows 7 ultimate, unfortunately it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Re-register `vbscript.dll` file to fix this.

Open an elevated Command Prompt window. by clicking on Start -> All Programs  > Accessories. Right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.

Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll`

You should see the following message after running the command:

`DllRegisterServer in vbscript.dll succeeded.`

Close any gadgets and open them again. If that does not help, restart Windows.

Comment: That does the trick. Had to restart though.

Answer (score 1):

First off I'm running Windows 7 on a Dell XPS 17 l702x.

Well all the command prompt fixes did nothing, I found an answer that helped me. You don't have to restart your computer.

- First close all your gadgets
- Go your `C:\` drive
- Go to `Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar`

AppData is a hidden folder, enable your hidden folders. Here you want to delete the `settings.ini` file.

When the file is deleted, run your calendar.